# Add a link on second form to show the previous form after Toggle

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I've two forms; Login and Register. I' m using jQuery toggle method to switch to the Register form. Only the problem is I don't know how can I add some link on my Register form so that onclick user can go back to Login form.

Please note that I've multilingual website and I need translation so I don't want to replace text in script.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

  $('.register').click(function() {
    // Toggle register form and enable inputs
    // with regular jQuery toggle
    $('form').find('input').toggle();
    $('form').find('label').toggle();
    $('form').find('span').toggle();
    $('form').find('small').toggle();
    $("#outer").hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <form method="post" action="" class="my-3" id="login_form">

    <label for="email" class="sr-only col-form-label text-md-right"></label>
    <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Username">

    <label for="password" class="sr-only col-form-label text-md-right"></label>
    <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password">

    <input type="submit" value="Login" class="submit_form">
  </form>

  <form id="register_forms" action="">
    <small style="display:none">Create New Account</small>

    <label for="register_name"></label>
    <input placeholder="Name" style="display: none" id="register_name" type="text" name="register_name" />

    <label for="register_email"></label>
    <input placeholder="Email" style="display: none" id="register_email" type="email" name="register_email" />

    <input style="display: none" id="my-register" type="submit" value="Continue" class="submit_form my-4">

    <div id="outer">
      <div id="inner">
        <a href="#" class="register">Don't have an account? Register Here!</a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try something like this:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var $loginForm = $('#login_form');
  var $registerForm = $('#register_forms');
  
  $('.register').click(function() {
    $registerForm.toggle();
    $loginForm.toggle();
  });
  
  $('.login').click(function() {
    $loginForm.toggle();
    $registerForm.toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <form method="post" action="" class="my-3" id="login_form">

    <label for="email" class="sr-only col-form-label text-md-right"></label>
    <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Username">

    <label for="password" class="sr-only col-form-label text-md-right"></label>
    <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password">

    <input type="submit" value="Login" class="submit_form">
    <div id="outer">
      <div id="inner">
        <a href="#" class="register">Don't have an account? Register Here!</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>

  <form style="display: none" id="register_forms" action="">
    <small>Create New Account</small>

    <label for="register_name"></label>
    <input placeholder="Name"  id="register_name" type="text" name="register_name" />

    <label for="register_email"></label>
    <input placeholder="Email" id="register_email" type="email" name="register_email" />

    <input id="my-register" type="submit" value="Continue" class="submit_form my-4">

    <div id="outer">
      <div id="inner">
        <a href="#" class="login">Already have an account? Login Here!</a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </form>

</div>
```

Comment: Perfect Working !
Amazing .. God Bless you friend :)